# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am getting this error on my project in Xcode;

NSRangeException
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

```
I think the line is here in my initial controller.m file;

            Session *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString* strDate = [LoadSessionController GetTimeString:item.mCreateDate];
            cell1.title = @"Restore last session";
            cell1.date = strDate;
            cell1.ago = [LoadSessionController GetBeforeTimeString:item.mCreateDate];   
            cell1.image = item.mThumbnail;
            cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
            cell = cell1;
            break;
        }



As the crash log is this;

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x328c429e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x395a697a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3280fb70 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 160
3   ColorSplash                     0x0001722a 0x1000 + 90666
4   UIKit                           0x3861f540 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 408
5   UIKit                           0x38604306 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1306
6   UIKit                           0x3861b7c2 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 202
7   UIKit                           0x385d77fe -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 254
8   QuartzCore                      0x3a2abd5e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
9   QuartzCore                      0x3a2ab8fc CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
10  QuartzCore                      0x3a2ac830 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
11  QuartzCore                      0x3a2ac216 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 234
12  QuartzCore                      0x3a2ac024 CA::Transaction::commit() + 312
13  UIKit                           0x385dd8e6 _afterCACommitHandler + 122
14  CoreFoundation                  0x328996c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
15  CoreFoundation                  0x328979bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
16  CoreFoundation                  0x32897d12 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
17  CoreFoundation                  0x3280aeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3280ad44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
19  GraphicsServices                0x35d4f2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
20  UIKit                           0x386282f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
```

But I am convinced the array isn't empty, but perhaps the newer version of iOS requires a different answer to just the :0

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks,

Chris

EDIT - Some more info;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCN_WIDTH, SCN_HEIGHT);
    [self.view setFrame: frame];

    self.dataArray = [LoadSessionController loadTableData:NO];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = ROW_HEIGHT;
}
```

...Loadsessioncontroller is;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellID";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (CustomCell *)[[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];
    }

    Session *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[self getDataIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSString* strDate = [LoadSessionController GetTimeString:item.mCreateDate];
    cell.title = @"Load saved session";
    cell.date = strDate;
    cell.ago = [LoadSessionController GetBeforeTimeString:item.mCreateDate];    
    cell.image = item.mThumbnail;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

NSInteger TimeSort(Session *obj1, Session *obj2, void *reverse) {
    if ((NSInteger *)reverse == NO) {
       if ([obj1.mCreateDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < [obj2.mCreateDate timeIntervalSinceNow])
           return NSOrderedAscending;
        else
            return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {
        if ([obj1.mCreateDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > [obj2.mCreateDate timeIntervalSinceNow])
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else
            return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}

+ (NSMutableArray*) loadTableData:(BOOL) bLoadRestoreData
{
    NSMutableArray* ret = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString* path =[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    int i;
    int nStartNo = 1;
    if (bLoadRestoreData)
        nStartNo = 0;

    for (i = nStartNo; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if ([Session exist:path index:i])
        {
            Session* one = [[Session alloc] init];
            [one read:path index:i];
            [ret addObject:one];
            [one release];
        }
    }

    [ret sortUsingFunction:TimeSort context:self];
    return ret;
}

+ (NSString*) GetTimeString:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:
                                    (kCFCalendarUnitHour|kCFCalendarUnitMinute|kCFCalendarUnitYear|kCFCalendarUnitMonth|kCFCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:date];

    //[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Saved %02d/%02d/%02d  %02d:%02d", components.year, components.month, components.day,
                      components.hour, components.minute];
}

#define TIME_SUFFIX(a) (((a)>1)?"s":"")
+ (NSString*)   GetBeforeTimeString:(NSDate*) date
{
    NSTimeInterval ago = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];

    unsigned int temp = -ago;

    int days = temp / (3600*24); temp = temp % (3600 * 24);
    int hours = temp / 3600; temp = temp % 3600;
    int minutes = temp / 60; temp = temp % 60;
    int seconds = temp;

    if (days == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d second%s ago", 
                seconds, TIME_SUFFIX(seconds)];
    }
    else if (days == 0 && hours == 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minute%s %d second%s ago", 
                minutes, TIME_SUFFIX(minutes), seconds, TIME_SUFFIX(seconds)];
    }
    else if (days == 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hour%s %d minute%s ago", 
                hours, TIME_SUFFIX(hours), minutes, TIME_SUFFIX(minutes)];
    }
    else {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d day%s %d hour%s ago", 
                days, TIME_SUFFIX(days), hours, TIME_SUFFIX(hours)];
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the code where you initialize and fill your array with data.

Comment: dataArray is definitely empty at this moment.

Comment: wild guess: you're array is empty :D - you cant access any content in the array because there is none and thats not possible. the problem is 100% where you attempt to fill it

Comment: Rest assured, your array is empty at this point. Add a breakpoint to that array access and do a `po dataArray`in the lldb command line.

Answer (score 4):

"But I am convinced the array isn't empty, but perhaps the newer version of iOS requires a different answer to just the :0"

No, this is not the case. Your array is definitely empty. Just log your array before the statement where you think the problem is, and see what you get. If you need to check whether an array is empty, you can either check if array.count is 0 or if array.lastObject is nil.

Answer (score 1):

As your error message says, your `dataArray` is empty. Either you don't fill it at all, or you access it before filling it.

Comment: Whereabout do I check where the dataArray is? Sorry this code is something I have struggled (clearly lol!) on, as I am merging it into an existing project of mine.

Comment: search for dataArray = for a start :))

Comment: Hmm, there is a few here are some;
- (void)dealloc {
 if (dataArray != nil)
 {
  [dataArray release];
  dataArray = nil;
 }

Comment: self.dataArray = [LoadSessionController loadTableData:NO];

Comment: Please update your question with information about in which method the line `Session *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];` is called, where the line `self.dataArray = [LoadSessionController loadTableData:NO];` is called and with the code of the method `+loadTableData` in your `LoadSessionController`.

Comment: Hi I have added this to the original question, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The array is empty for sure, verify it through an assertion:

```
NSAssert( [dataArray count] >=1, @"Array is empty");
```

Then post the code with which you think to fill the array.

Comment: a mere comment. not even formulated as an answer

Comment: That's all I can say, I know that dataArray is empty but I cannot see the rest of the code.